# How to know if a person has elinati shani (sade sati), ashtami shani or ardha ashtami shani?

Tags: astrology

How does one know if a person has shani?

Is it through astrology? Are there any ways to know this? Please explain.

Comment: If you are interested in an explanation, please send me a chat invite.

Comment: When shani comes in the twelfth house, the sade sati starts and remains so until shani crosses out of the second house into the third.